# Include TinyMCE plugins with Wordpress wp_editor?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tinymce

Currently writing a plugin for WordPress, this includes a TinyMCE plugin for the builtin editor of WordPress.

However, when I print a TinyMCE editor at a custom admin page with:

```
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

The editor does not come with the aforementioned plugins. How would I go about including them with wp_editor?

Thank you.

Comment: have a look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48356/creating-a-wp-editor-instance-with-custom-tinymce-buttons

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just me being stupid. I created the WordPress menu BEFORE adding the TinyMCE plugin..

So for other people getting stuck on something this silly, make sure you have

```
add_filter("mce_external_plugins", array( $this, 'add_tinymce_plugin' ) );
add_filter('mce_buttons', array( $this, 'register_my_tc_button' ) );
// Rest of the code for adding your TinyMCE Plugins
// ...
```

Before you start throwing around your

```
wp_editor()
```

expecting it to work!

Comment: This did not work for me. What are the functions for add_tinymce_plugin and register_my_tc_button? WordPress should already have these functions like they do on Posts page?