# calling wp_editor getting error getContent null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, tinymce

I am calling `wordpress`'s `tinyMCE` from `php` and assigning it's contents through `ajax` to a form array key.
I keep on getting error: `Cannot read property 'getContent' of null`.
I read thought [Wordpress wp_editor() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784295/wordpress-wp-editor-not-working) and [Include TinyMCE plugins with Wordpress wp_editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926982/include-tinymce-plugins-with-wordpress-wp-editor) & others but still can't get `tinyMCE`'s content into `form array`.

**`JS`:**

```
var form            =   {
            action:             "submit_user_data",
            content:            tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(),
            title:              $("#inputTitle").val(),
            ingredients:        $("#inputIngredients").val(),
            time:               $("#inputTime").val(),
            utensils:           $("#inputUtensils").val(),
            level:              $("#inputLevel").val(),
            meal_type:          $("#inputMealType").val()
        };
```

**`PHP`:**

```
wp_editor( '', 'tinymcecontenteditor' );
```

The issue is originated at the `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` call.
Any ideas?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Following through on the call to `'tinymce`'s methods & functions, I could not find anything wrong with the call.
But somehow (still can't figure it out do this one's left for the public) I noticed that calling `tinymce` from a `jquery` as mentioned does not give access to it's contents (obviously...dah..).
What I found out I need to do is, instead of calling the `getContent` function, I had to trigger the [`triggerSave`](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.triggerSave) function and the get the `val` of the object by `id`, so:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
var contents = $("#tinymcecontenteditor").val();
```

Before I assign it's contents to the `form array`.

Form array changed to `content:            contents,`.

[shahnbaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598975/848677) pointed me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem lies with your WordPress integration. As long as the TinyMCE JS is in the page, `activeEditor` should always return the editor instance.